# How can I split a list into multiple lists?

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to convert `[CS-PP-GE-RI-ET]` which is the first element in a list to:

```
[CS]
[CS-PP]
[CS-PP-GE]
[CS-PP-GE-RI]
[CS-PP-GE-RI-ET]
```

Here is what I have got so far:

```
data = ['CS-PP-GE-RI-ET',
        'CS-PP-ET-GE',
        'CS-PP-ET-GE-BD',
        'CS-PP-ET-GE',
        'CS-PP-ET-CD-PI-GE']

word0 = []
word1 = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    # print(i)  # 0 1 2 3 4 ... however many elements are in data
    split = data[i].split('-')  # prints CS-PP-GE-RI-ET ...
    # print(split)  # this prints ['CS', 'PP', 'GE', 'RI', 'ET'] for each element
    for j in range(len(split)-1):  # you have to use range(len()-1 to iterate all the way to the end of the index count
        # print(split[j])  # this prints each element CS PP GE RI ET CS PP ...
        # word1.append(split[j])
        temp0 = split[j]
        word0.append(temp0)
        temp1 = split[j + 1]
        temp3 = temp0 + '-' + temp1
        word0.append((temp3))

    print(word0)
```

This is what I get though:

```
['CS', 'CS-PP', 'PP', 'PP-GE', 'GE', 'GE-RI', 'RI', 'RI-ET']
['CS', 'CS-PP', 'PP', 'PP-GE', 'GE', 'GE-RI', 'RI', 'RI-ET', 'CS', 'CS-PP', 'PP', 'PP-ET', 'ET', 'ET-GE']
...
```

I know I am missing a basic understanding of `str` and `append()` but can't seem to figure it out.

The final result should be:

```
[CS]
[CS-PP]
[CS-PP-GE]
[CS-PP-GE-RI]
[CS-PP-GE-RI-ET]
[CS]
[CS-PP]
[CS-PP-ET]
[CS-PP-ET-GE]
[CS]
...
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)  here

```
from itertools import accumulate

l = 'CS-PP-GE-RI-ET'.split('-')
print(*accumulate(l, lambda x, y: '-'.join([x, y])), sep='\n')

CS
CS-PP
CS-PP-GE
CS-PP-GE-RI
CS-PP-GE-RI-ET
```

---

For a general solution you can do:

```
data = ['CS-PP-GE-RI-ET',
        'CS-PP-ET-GE',
        'CS-PP-ET-GE-BD',
        'CS-PP-ET-GE',
        'CS-PP-ET-CD-PI-GE']

def acc(s):
    l = s.split('-')
    func = lambda x, y: '-'.join([x, y])
    return '\n'.join(accumulate(l, func))
```

---

```
print(*map(acc, data), sep='\n\n')

CS
CS-PP
CS-PP-GE
CS-PP-GE-RI
CS-PP-GE-RI-ET

CS
CS-PP
CS-PP-ET
CS-PP-ET-GE

CS
CS-PP
CS-PP-ET
CS-PP-ET-GE
CS-PP-ET-GE-BD

CS
CS-PP
CS-PP-ET
CS-PP-ET-GE

CS
CS-PP
CS-PP-ET
CS-PP-ET-CD
CS-PP-ET-CD-PI
CS-PP-ET-CD-PI-GE
```

Comment: This solution doesn't make sense. If variable `l` is data, this just prints out the original list.

Comment: This solution considers `l` to be the inital stated by OP @charlesreid1

Comment: Output from this script is just `CS-PP-GE-RI-ET`

Comment: Updated @charlesreid1

Comment: @yatu how can I remove the `CS` that is placed at the end after each iteration?

Comment: `at the end after each iteration`? Not sure I follow. It's at the beginning of each line right? @MasoodQaim

Comment: @yatu sorry, I miss read the output. Thanks! I'll learn about itertools, seems very useful.

Comment: Glad it helped @MasoodQaim

Answer (score 1):

This should write all your items into a list containing list, since your lists will need a place holder.

```
wrapper_list = list()
my_list = ['CS-PP-GE-RI-ET']
for str_item in my_list:
    temp_string = ""
    combined_string_list = list(str_item.split('-'))
    for index in range(len(str_item)):
         wrapper_list.append(["-".join(combined_string_list[0:index+1])])
print(wrapper_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this:

```
for word in data:
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] == '-':
            print([ word[:i] ])
    print([ word ])
```

Or with list comprehension:

```
print( '\n'.join( str([ word[:i] ]) 
                  for word in data
                  for i in range(len(word))
                  if word[i] == '-' or i == len(word) - 1 ) )
```